# How can I make Git open commit messages in RStudio on windows?

Tags: git, rstudio

In general I know that I can use `git config --global core.editor "app"` using the list of apps in the git documentation to change the default text editor in which commit messages are opened.

However, I primarily work in RStudio so I was messing around and trying to figure out if I can force commit messages to open in the RStudio text editor. But, my office machine is Windows and I am not used to the Windows command prompt, which does not have the `open` command that I am familiar with, so I cannot simply use `"open -a RStudio"` here.

When I set `git config --global core.editor "start RStudio"`, the file opens, but Git returns an error that says "aborting message due to empty commit." So I try `"start RStudio /WAIT"` instead, but I get the same error AND a new RStudio window opens instead of the file opening in the same window. So then I tried `"start RStudio /B /WAIT"` instead and the same thing happens.

Is there a command I can use here that will open a commit message in the same RStudio window, and tell Git to wait for a response, or do I have to use one of the editors listed in the Git documentation?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using the RStudio git integration tools directly rather than working on the command line?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no, I just don't like having to click the buttons. I tried using Nano in the terminal window (via git bash) but it is really laggy on my machine so I thought opening messages in the RStudio editor would be the next best thing.

Comment: Does RStudio have key bindings? I hardly use the command line any more because I use an editor for my programming. And I use key bindings as much as possible so I clicking with the mouse is very minimal (basically non-existent for git operations).

Comment: At least as far as I'm aware, there are keybindings to switch between the editor and the terminal, but no option to set keybindings for Git integration. Of course it is possible to use something like notepad to edit commit messages, so this is more of a curiosity than anything I guess.

Comment: RStudio has several key bindings for git operations. See the link in my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using the git integrations directly in RStudio. Since you don't like clicking the mouse, learn [the key bindings](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts) for Git operations:

> Git/SVN
>
> Description   Windows & Linux Mac
>
> Diff active source document   Ctrl+Alt+D  Ctrl+Option+D
>
> Commit changes    Ctrl+Alt+M  Ctrl+Option+M
>
> Scroll diff view  Ctrl+Up/Down    Ctrl+Up/Down
>
> Stage/Unstage (Git)   Spacebar    Spacebar
>
> Stage/Unstage and move to next (Git)  Enter   Return

(see the previous link for better formatting)

Comment: I often need to do other git operations so I prefer to use the terminal for git (and there is a keybinding to shift focus to the terminal). I appreciate the help but this does not really answer my question, which is whether or not it is possible to configure Git to correctly use RStudio to open and edit long commit messages.

Comment: @wz-billings Thanks for the feedback. You are right that I didn't really answer your question here. Good luck with figuring it out.